# imapsync User is authenticated but not connected

Tags: outlook

I'm using imapsync to migration email from outlook (email domain) to new server.
But it show error:

```
Host1 capability: IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
Host2 capability: IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS
Host1: NAMESPACE request failed for imap-mail.outlook.com: * BYE Connection closed. 14; 11 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
Give the separator character with the --sep1 option,
the folowing listing of folders may help you to find it:
Most of the time it is character . or /
so try --sep1 . or --sep1 /
```

When I using telnet to connect outlook server, it response:

```
* OK Outlook.com IMAP4rev1 server version 17.4.0.0 ready (BAY451-IMAP140)
1 LOGIN user@domain.com ******
1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
2 NAMESPACE
2 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
3 LIST "" "*"
3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
* BYE Connection closed. 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Exchange and Office365 will accept connections and authenticate users by their username and password when the user doesn't have IMAP permissions. No error is given until the first IMAP command is issued, at which point it gives "User is authenticated but not connected".

To correct this, open the permissions for the user on the server and ensure that IMAP is selected.

Answer (score -2):

See http://imapsync.lamiral.info/FAQ.d/FAQ.Exchange.txt

Q. Exchange fails with "User is authenticated but not connected".

R. "The message User is authenticated but not connected is due to a 
   bug in the Exchange server's IMAP implementation. If the client 
   presents a valid user name but an invalid password, the server 
   accepts the login, but subsequent commands fail with the 
   aforementioned error message." Source:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164823/user-is-authenticated-but-not-connected-after-changing-my-exchange-password
Thanks to James Abbottsmith for this link and explanation at
https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync/issues/32#issuecomment-153561647

Comment: I try using Outlook anh Thunderbird then it show same error User is authenticated but not connected.

Comment: So it looks like it's really an invalid password. Change it.

Comment: I change password to simple word. But it same error. I think error from imap server